split function: best practice
I have some experience with FP and I found this function online which splits a list in two halves:
let split l =
  let n = List.length l in
  let rec splitAt k l =
    match k, l with
    | 0, _     -> [], l
    | _, []    -> [], []
    | _, x::xs ->
      let l, r = splitAt (k-1) xs in
      x::l, r 
  in splitAt (n/2) l

It works and I can see why but it seems a little strange in my mind. If someone had asked me to write a function which splits a list this what I would write:
let split2 l =
  let n = List.length l in
  let rec splitAt k acc l =
    if k=0 then (List.rev acc, l) else
    match l with
    | [] -> [], []
    | h::t -> splitAt (k-1) (h::acc) t
  in splitAt (n/2) [] l

I think, if someone had given me the second function without its name it would be 100% clear immediately after I read it, but the first function seemed a tad more difficult to understand at first.
So my question is which is better, in terms of functional-style/OCaml best practices?

Disclaimer: I am talking about the essence of these functions (the logic with which they implement the list splitting), not syntax things (e.g. the use of if-then-else in my code instead of a pattern-matching)

If the order of element is not important - as in the split function
of mergesort for instance - and you just need to split the list into
two sub-lists of same size (up to 1), you can use this version:
let split l =
  let rec loop (acc1, acc2) = function
    | [] -> (acc1, acc2)
    | [h] -> (h :: acc1, acc2)
    | h1 :: h2 :: t -> loop (h1 :: acc1, h2 :: acc2) t
  in
  loop ([], []) l

It distributes the elements of the initial list to the two accumulators each in turn.
Or this one, which is shorter, as it always distributes the first
element to the first accumulator, but switches the two accumulators
at each recursive call
let split l =
  let rec loop ((acc1, acc2) as acc) = function
    | [] -> acc
    | h :: t -> loop (acc2, h :: acc1) t
  in
  loop ([], []) l

I find those more satisfying as they dont require you to think in terms of length, and avoid the redundant-ish pattern-matching

Yes of course your functions are much more elegant than those I provided (especially the second one that I had never thought of), but let's assume that order matters in my case..

Your version has the advantage of being tail-recursive by means of an accumulator and therefore not suffering a stack overflow working on a very large list. Continuation passing would be another way of accomplishing this, but the accumulator approach is far more idiomatic for OCaml.
As you test whether k is zero or not, and your match only happens when it is not zero, the match against the empty list is unnecessary, aside from silencing a warning about a non-exhaustive match. Knowing this, you might explicitly silence that warning.
let split2 l =
  let n = List.length l in
  let rec splitAt k acc l =
    if k=0 then (List.rev acc, l)
    else
      let [@warning "-8"] h::t = l in
      splitAt (k-1) (h::acc) t
  in 
  splitAt (n/2) [] l

Since you're iterating over the first half of the list twice anyway,  you could implement this in terms of take and drop functions, which are straightforward to implement. We can make take tail-recursive with tail_mod_cons.
let split lst =
  let n = List.length lst in
  let[@tail_mod_cons] rec take n lst =
    match n, lst with
    | 0, _ -> []
    | _, [] -> invalid_arg "List not long enough."
    | _, x::xs -> x :: take (n - 1) xs
  in
  let rec drop n lst =
    match n, lst with
    | 0, _ -> lst
    | _, [] -> invalid_arg "List not long enough."
    | _, _::xs -> drop (n - 1) xs
  in
  (take (n / 2) lst, drop (n / 2) lst)

If you go down this road, you could use the standard library to do some of the heavy lifting.
let split lst =
  let seq = List.to_seq lst in
  let half = List.length lst / 2 in
  (seq |> Seq.take half |> List.of_seq,
   seq |> Seq.drop half |> List.of_seq)


Well, yes my version is tail recursive but on the other hand it passes through the elements of the first halve of the list 2 times (one with the recursive calls to splitAt and one at the end for the List.rev function). Though I don't know if the compiler is smart enough to apply an optimization there...

Usually when you're looking to optimize something like that, your best bet is to look at the data structure you're using, the problem you're trying to solve, and ask yourself if they're a good fit.
